# www subdomain looks different than main domain on Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, apache, flask

I'm working on a website which looks different when the browser is pointed to root domain and when pointed to "www" subdomain. The canvas width, font sizes, image sizes vary slightly between the root domain and "www" subdomain.

EDIT 1: This happens only on Google Chrome. On firefox, both pages look same.

Please refer to these external links to my site in Google Chrome.

1. Without "www" - https://myshaadiwale.com

[image: Root MyShaadiWale screenshot]

2. With "www" subdomain - https://www.myshaadiwale.com

[image: Subdomain MyShaadiWale screenshot]

Even the browser console does not show anything amiss. What could possibly cause this difference?

The website is based on python flask+apache stack. The apache configuration file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName myshaadiwale.com
    ServerAlias www.myshaadiwale.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /root/ssl/myshaadiwale.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/ssl/myshaadiwale.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /root/ssl/intermediate.crt

    WSGIDaemonProcess msw user=live group=live threads=5 python-path=/home/live/msw/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/live/msw/msw.wsgi

    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
            <IfModule mod_filter.c>
                    # these are known to be safe with MSIE 6
                    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml

                    # everything else may cause problems with MSIE 6
                    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
                    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript application/javascript application/ecmascript
                    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
                    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
            </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    <Directory /home/live/msw>
            #Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
            WSGIScriptReloading On
            WSGIProcessGroup msw
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            WSGIPassAuthorization On
            Options All
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myshaadiwale.com
    ServerAlias www.myshaadiwale.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.myshaadiwale.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please include the differences in the question, preferably a screenshot. They are pixel identical as far as I can see. Also include details about what browsers you tested.

Comment: @DarkFalcon - Sorry, I forgot to mention that this happens only on Google Chrome. I'll upload the screenshots shortly.

Comment: Does the hostname appear anywhere in the page?  Could it just be that reference that causes the slight difference?

Comment: I don't see any difference in Chrome

Comment: @FestiveTurnip - Just added screenshots. The content seems to swell up when i point to "www".

Comment: @yftse - No. There are no direct references to host itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pages are still pixel identical. The problem is that you have changed the browser zoom level and Chrome remembers this on a per-domain basis. Press `Ctrl` `0` to reset the zoom to 100% and the pages will again be identical. Pressing `Ctrl` `+` will reproduce the problem exactly as shown in the screenshots.

Comment: Thats it! I swear I tested on my colleague's laptop too. Feeling stupid now!